# how to display a snapshot of a current map in Info after clicking disclosure from annotation

Tags: iphone

After clicking on the disclosure button from an annotation, you will end up with a View called **Info**. At this screen, on the top left corner, there is a small images which is a snapshot of your current location. Does anybody know how to get the snapshot from the map and display in Info screen
There is an image so that you can easily know what I am talking about
Please help, all answers are welcomed here. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your going to want to use CoreGraphics to render the map to an image.

```
if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frameYouWantToCopy.size, NO, 0.0);
}
else {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(frameYouWantToCopy.size);
}
[mapView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return result;
```

Comment: I tried and the image's size is not in a good shape. What I did is **     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(32, 32), NO, 0.0);**

Comment: I tried and the image's size is not in a good shape.The length is as twice as height and it is not showing an annotation on it... What I did is *UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(32, 32), NO, 0.0);*...The rest are the same from your comment.

Answer (score 0):

i have got the solution to this point
when you click info button just set the map to the centre. and take the image from there 
what i have done so far is
taken one image mapImageview in .h and used that imageview to store image of the annotation
 first remember the coordinates of the pin you have dropped
and then just centre to that region by calling the function

```
-(void)setMaptocentre:(double)lat (double)long
 {
     MKCoordinateRegion region;
     region.center.latitude=lat;
     region.center.longitude=long;

     MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta=10;
    span.longitudeDelta=10;
    region.span =span;   
    [MapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
 } 

-(IBAction)infoPressed:(id)sender
 {
    [self setMaptocentre: rememberedLat rememberdLong];
   //here the rememberedlat and rememberedLong are the latitude and longitude you have 
   // saved at the time of pin drop. the function brings the pin to centre of map
   //  and then does the following part to take the image, where it includes the pin

   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGRectMake(150, 200, 100, 100).size);
   CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
   CGContextTranslateCTM(c,-105, -130); 
   [self.view.layer renderInContext:c];
   UIImage* viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewImage);
   mapImageview.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
 }
```

i know you get to the answer uptill now but for the shake of others, i am posting here
thanks